# python3 pip upgrade NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined

Tags: python, pip

If I want to install a package with `pip3` I receive following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/habapp/bin/pip3", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/habapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "/opt/habapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/habapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand
  File "/opt/habapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.req.constructors import (
  File "/opt/habapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .req_file import parse_requirements
  File "/opt/habapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_file.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pip._internal.req.constructors import (
  File "/opt/habapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/constructors.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pip._internal.req.req_install import InstallRequirement
  File "/opt/habapp/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.pep517.wrappers import Pep517HookCaller
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pep517-0.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pep517/wrappers.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/resources.py", line 11, in <module>
    from typing import Iterable, Iterator, Optional, Set, Union   # noqa: F401
  File "/home/openhabvm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/typing.py", line 782, in <module>
    AnyStr = TypeVar('AnyStr', bytes, unicode)
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined
(habapp) openhabvm@OpenHABVM:/opt/habapp$ ^C
(habapp) openhabvm@OpenHABVM:/opt/habapp$ deactivate
openhabvm@OpenHABVM:/opt/habapp$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 19, in <module>
    sys.exit(_main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.req.constructors import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .req_file import parse_requirements
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_file.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pip._internal.req.constructors import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/constructors.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pip._internal.req.req_install import InstallRequirement
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.pep517.wrappers import Pep517HookCaller
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pep517-0.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pep517/wrappers.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/resources.py", line 11, in <module>
    from typing import Iterable, Iterator, Optional, Set, Union   # noqa: F401
  File "/home/openhabvm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/typing.py", line 782, in <module>
    AnyStr = TypeVar('AnyStr', bytes, unicode)
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 72, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 32, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from apt.package import Package as Package, Version as Version
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/package.py", line 42, in <module>
    from typing import (Any, Iterable, Iterator, List, Optional, Set,
  File "/home/openhabvm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/typing.py", line 782, in <module>
    AnyStr = TypeVar('AnyStr', bytes, unicode)
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 19, in <module>
    sys.exit(_main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.req.constructors import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .req_file import parse_requirements
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_file.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pip._internal.req.constructors import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/constructors.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pip._internal.req.req_install import InstallRequirement
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.pep517.wrappers import Pep517HookCaller
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pep517-0.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pep517/wrappers.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/resources.py", line 11, in <module>
    from typing import Iterable, Iterator, Optional, Set, Union   # noqa: F401
  File "/home/openhabvm/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/typing.py", line 782, in <module>
    AnyStr = TypeVar('AnyStr', bytes, unicode)
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined
```

This also occurs if I want to upgrade pip:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 to 20.04. I am sure that I have deleted Python 2.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python3
```

And i used `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10` without errors

```
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3 to provide /usr/bin/python (python) in auto mode
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For python3, unicode was renamed to str

Comment: Why do you have Python 2 and 3 libraries active at the same time?

Comment: @KlausD.  I uninstalled python 2. Better I purged it. I can't change it. It will really not change it. I also purged and reinstalled python3. And i used 'sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10' without errors 'update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/python3 to provide /usr/bin/python (python) in auto mode'.

Comment: Looks like an environment error.  You should make sure `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` is not on your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: You don't seem to be using a virtual environment. I recommend using them when developing python, it will help you a lot with this kind of problems.

Comment: Thanks @Iguananaut I removed it from the `PYTHONPATH`